# mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mysqladmin

Today (2015-05-02) I upgraded my Linux system via apt-get update and
apt-get upgrade whereas mysql, mysqladmin and a lot more packages
have been updated. The mysql-server-5.5 runs and I can login and do all
the typical database operations but when I type:

```
user@ubuntu:~# mysqladmin proc
```

I get the following error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Formerly I could solve this issue by simple setting the mysql root password new.
This does not solve the issue anymore:

```
user@ubuntu:~# sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

How do I get the mysqladmin up again without reinstalling mysql?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Short version*: If your MySQL user `root` needs a password to connect, it might be a good idea to have `mysqladmin` provide that password ;)

*Longer version*: Your MySQL user `root` seems to need a password to connect

> setting the mysql root password new

But `mysqladmin` tries to connect *without* a password

> 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

And `mysqladmin` does that because you're not telling it otherwise ;)

`mysqladmin`, like other MySQL-related command line tools (`mysql`, `mysqldump`, `mysqlshow` etc.), offers options to provide such access data.

- `h`: Which host to connect to. If not provided, `localhost` is assumed
- `u`: Which user to connect as. If not provided, `root` is assumed
- `p`: Which password to use. If not provided, no password is used

You should be able to use something like

```
mysqladmin -uroot -pmysupersecretpassword proc
```

(be aware that there's no space between the options and their values). You can also have MySQL ask you for the password like

```
mysqladmin -uroot -p proc
```

With that, MySQL should give you a prompt where you can enter your password.

Comment: Hello, this solved my problem but I have a question. I am not able to login using `mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` , contains of debian.cnf: `https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n7n8zTZBM2/` can you able to help me?

Comment: @SiddheshNan Judging from first glance, what you're doing should work. But comments on existing questions and answers aren't meant to ask new questions. That's what, well, new questions are for ;) So I would advise you to search whether another question or answer solves your specific problem, and if there's none, ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is going good and fine except for being able to get MySQL to work, Everything was working fine except status was failed.

[MySQL Service Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab4w9.png)

Try this if you are working in **fedora 3x**

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo dnf install community-mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysqld.service
```

**After this try**

```
sudo dnf reinstall community-mysql-server
```